# Что произойдет AJAX-запросом, при отправке на выключенный компьютер?

Tags: javascript, ajax

*недавно приступил к изучению AJAX-технологии*

Пишу одно веб-приложение отправляющее данные клиента на сервер (Имя, Адрес объекта, Контактный номер телефона), а сервер- обычный комп, который принимает и сохраняет данные, и может быть выключенным (от этого фактора и вопрос).

Comment: просто в fail вернёт как 502 или что-то типа того. В success ничего не придёт

Comment: Отключите сервер и проверьте, сделайте запрос

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В панели разработчика браузера на вкладке сеть есть возможность отследить результат запроса (можно посмотреть заголовки запроса, тело ответа и содержимое ответа на запрос).
Чтобы попасть в панель разработчика в хроме нажми F12.
в браузере перейди по нужному тебе URL, открой панель разработчика, перейди на вкладку Сеть(Network) и выбирай нужный запрос для просмотра информации о нем.
Перед запросом останови Сервер и проверь ответ запроса.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но вопрос заключается в том, что произойдет с запросом при отправке на выключенный сервер (он не отправиться, он исчезнет или он останется там висеть до включения сервака)?

Comment: Запрос отправляется и клиент ожидает ответ в течении определенного времени. Сервер не отвечает, время ожидания ответа превышается. В таком случае браузер выдает ошибку вроде этой `net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`(* ошибка выводится в консоли на панели разработчика), ну а запрос нигде висеть не остается.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понятно.